# Mathematical terminology for primes $(q+1)/2$ such that $q$ is also prime

Tags: prime-numbers, terminology

So I know that if both $p$ and $2p + 1$ are primes, then $p$ is a *Sophie Germain prime* [from the Prime Glossary](https://primes.utm.edu/glossary/page.php?sort=SophieGermainPrime).

My question is this:  How do we call a prime $r=(q+1)/2$ such that $q=2r-1$ is also prime?

I searched for the first $6$ terms via OEIS and I got sequence [A005383](http://oeis.org/A005383):

> > $$3, 5, 13, 37, 61, 73, \ldots$$

However, there does not seem to be any explicit mention of a specific terminology for such primes $r=(q+1)/2$ in the literature and on the Internet.

Does anybody here know of an existing terminology for such primes $r$?

Thanks!

Comment: If it doesn't have a special name on OEIS then it probably doesn't have one at all.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

$r$ is the base of a [Cunningham chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_chain) of the second kind. A Sophie-Germain prime is the base of a Cunningham chain of the first kind.