# I have found a proof that there does not exist any odd perfect number, Am I Correct?

Tags: number-theory, solution-verification, perfect-numbers

[To Verify the proof click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/KARtM.jpg)

I really cannot imagine I did it, My Intuition to send this here is just please God there must be a mistake in here, but if magically there is isn't, I will really say that I will die out of happiness.

Comment: $\frac{p_1^{\alpha+1} -1}{p_1 -1}$ doesn't need to *equal* $2$.  It only needs to be even.

Comment: The components $\frac {p_i^{\alpha} -1}{p_i -1}$ are not prime.  (Nor are they relatively prime to each other).  So although  $S_n$ is even and has a factor of $2$, it is not true that any of the $\frac {p_i^{\alpha} -1}{p_i -1}$ is equal to $2$.

Comment: Consider $\frac {p^{2k} + 1}{p-1} = 1 + p + p^2 + .... p^{2k-1}$ is always an even number but is never actually equal to $2$.  You have proven that that if $S_n = \prod \frac {p_i^{\alpha_i +1} -1}{p_i -1}$ there is exactly one $\alpha_i$ is odd.  All other $\alpha s$ are even.

Comment: @fleablood if that value[(p1^(a+1)/p1-1) don't mind I do not have the symbol of alpha that's why using a] is even but not 2 let's say 2 ^a where a is greater than 1 then Sum of factors would be divisible by 2^a and now Sum of factors is =2*n then n should be divisible by 2^(a-1) but since a >1 so a-1>0 hence we are saying here n is divisible by some positive power of 2 which means it's even which is wrong as n needs to be odd

Comment: Hence this value must be 2 only

Comment: Yes, components of that term are not prime, they must be of the form 2p where p is odd, Thanks for correcting me, Thank you very much.

Comment: @ShridharSharma:  Note that, following your logic, if $$2 = \frac{p^{k+1} - 1}{p - 1},$$ then necessarily $p$ is the **special prime** (satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$), which means that $\sigma(p^k) = 2$.  We do know that $\sigma(p^k) \equiv 1 + \ldots + 1 \equiv k + 1 \pmod 4$ (since $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$), and then $\sigma(p^k) \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ (since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$).  (Looks good so far.)  **However, notice that since $p$ is the special prime satisfying $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ implies that $k \geq 1$, then $$\sigma(p^k) \geq p^k + 1 \geq 6.$$**

Comment: @ShridharSharma:  Additionally, please consider learning how to typeset your mathematical equations using [MathJAX](https://math.stackexchange.com/help/notation).  (Linking to an off-site image is considered bad practice here, and will likely elicit downvotes/closure votes, since images are not indexed in search engines)

Comment: @fleablood:  Let $q^a n^2$ be an **odd perfect number** with special prime $q$ satisfying $q \equiv a \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and $\gcd(q,n)=1$.  Let $$n = \prod_{i=1}^{\omega(n)}{{q_i}^{\alpha_i}}$$ be the **prime factorization** of $n$.  From your comment [here](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4378485/i-have-found-a-proof-that-there-does-not-exist-any-odd-perfect-number-am-i-corr#comment9150840_4378485), you seem to be implying that $$\gcd\bigg(\sigma({q_u}^{2\alpha_u}),\sigma({q_v}^{2\alpha_v})\bigg) > 1$$ for all $v \neq u$.  How are you getting that?  Mind sharing a reference for that?

Comment: I don't want to discourage a high school student with a love of number theory, but questions asking to check a proof of an open problem are generally *not* popular here. Please see https://math.meta.stackexchange.com/q/19652/207316 & the links there

Comment: @ARNIEBEBITA-DRIS no.  I am implying $\gcd(\sigma(q_u^{2\alpha_u -1},q_v^{2\alpha_v -1}))$ is even.  Because $\sigma(q_u^{2\alpha_u -1}) = 1 + q_u + q_u^2 + ..... +q_u^{2\alpha_u -1})$ where is an *even* number of odd terms.

Comment: " if that value(p1^(a+1)/p1-1) is even but not 2 let's say 2 ^a where a is greater than 1"  It's not.  It is even of the form $2\cdot odd$.  You are correct that if $\sigma(n) = 2n$ and $n$ is odd then exactly one of the $\frac {p_i^{a_i +1}-1}{p_i-1}$ components must be even and it can't have an power two greater than $2^1$.   But it does not have to be equal $2$ (which would be impossible because it is $\ge 1+p_1$). Nor does it have to be equal to $2^k$ (which is not possible as $n$ is odd).  So it must equal to $2K$ for some odd $K$.  I doubt one can find a contradiction with that.

Comment: "components of that term are not prime, they must be of the form 2p where p is odd"  No, they do not.  The can be of the form $2K$ where $K$ is a composite odd number.

Answer (score 1):

**Comment converted to an answer:**

Note that, following your logic, if $$2 = \frac{p^{k+1} - 1}{p - 1},$$ then necessarily $p$ is the **special prime** (satisfying $p \equiv k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$), which means that $\sigma(p^k) = 2$.  We do know that $\sigma(p^k) \equiv 1 + \ldots + 1 \equiv k + 1 \pmod 4$ (since $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$), and then $\sigma(p^k) \equiv 2 \pmod 4$ (since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$).  (Looks good so far.)  **However, notice that since $p$ is the special prime satisfying $p \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ and since $k \equiv 1 \pmod 4$ implies that $k \geq 1$, then $$\sigma(p^k) \geq p^k + 1 \geq 6.$$**  This lower bound for $\sigma(p^k)$ clearly contradicts your result $\sigma(p^k)=2$.

Comment: Yes thanks for answering. I have acknowledged that it does need to to be 2 but it has to be 2p, thank you for suggesting. I am in grade 9 and I just solve number theory problems just for fun as I have an exceptional interest in number theory. I am still learning. I just thought that I can prove it but I have realised the actual mystery of this question.

Comment: Actually, it **does not necessarily follow** that $\sigma(p^k)/2$ is a prime (or even [**squarefree**](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Square-free_integer), for that matter).  (It does follow that if $\sigma(p^k)/2$ is prime, then $k=1$ from which it follows that $\sigma(p^k)/2 = (p+1)/2$ is the base of a [Cunningham chain](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cunningham_chain) of the second kind.) Refer to [this MSE question](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1294399) for more details.